# Where does qemu/virt-manager store connection strings?

Tags: configuration, connection, virt-manager

I'm migrating to a new laptop and have a decent number of Connections (not actual VMs) in virt-manager. I've grepped and cannot find any text file with data from the connection strings that appear when I open virt-manager.

None of these exist:
/etc/libvirt
~/.gconf/apps/virt-manager/

I've also used

```
grep -r "hostname" /home/acoder/
grep -r "hostname" /etc/
```

and came up empty-handed.

Where in Ubuntu/Linux Mint is virt-manager storing this config data? Is it stored in a binary file?